# Jquery setting time to input box on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am using JQM DateBox 2(http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) to set time in my JQM App. This is my HTML.

```
 <label for="mode7">Time :</label>
                    <input name="mode7" id="mode7" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timeflipbox", "useNewStyle":true}' />
```

Now here , i have to click on the DateBox control to populate the field with the time. I am trying to populate the time on page load in the format 09:53PM with my own script and the time can be changed by using the DateBox 2 Control.

Here is my script to populate time on page load ,it doesnt seem to work.What am i doing wrong below

```
 $(window).load(function () {
            var now = new Date(),
              now = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes();
            $("#mode7").html(now);
        });
```

JSFiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/ncsyC/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$("#mode").val(now);
```

Also I recommend using a library such as [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com) to do the formatting for you.

Comment: doesnt work mate . I have attached a JSfiddle link in my post.

Comment: @Boncek35 - your fiddle isnt loading jquery and throwing `$ is not defined` in the console.  otherwise, I agree with ced-b here...

Comment: @ced-b - closer to what he had, could have used a `on document ready` instead of the `on window load` and it would have worked...